# register form in php just reloading same page

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a register page for users who can register using email, with email activation and Google captcha. My register code is as follows:

```html
<?php
require_once('connect.php');
include('config.php');
include('recaptchalib.php');
$response = null;
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);
if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){

 if($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']){
  $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']
   );

 }

 if($response != null && $response->success){
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
  $verification_key = md5($username);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
  $password = md5($_POST['password']);
  $passwordagain = md5($_POST['passwordagain']);
  if($password == $passwordagain){
   $fmsg = "";

   $usernamesql = "SELECT * FROM `usermanagement` WHERE username='$username'";
   $usernameres = mysqli_query($connection, $usernamesql);
   $count = mysqli_num_rows($usernameres);
   if($count == 1){
    $fmsg .= "Username exists in Database, please try different user name";
   }

   $emailsql = "SELECT * FROM `usermanagement` WHERE email='$email'";
   $emailres = mysqli_query($connection, $emailsql);
   $emailcount = mysqli_num_rows($emailres);
   if($emailcount == 1){
    $fmsg .= "Email exists in Database, please reset your password";
   }


   echo $sql = "INSERT INTO `usermanagement` (username, email, password, verification_key) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', '$verification_key')";
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
   if($result){
    $smsg = "User Registered succesfully";
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
     require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

     $mail = new PHPMailer;

     $mail->isSMTP();
     $mail->Host = $smtphost;
     $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
     $mail->Username = $smtpuser;
     $mail->Password = $smtppass;
     $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
     $mail->Port = 465;

     $mail->setFrom('admin@teia.website', 'BookTheParty');
     $mail->addAddress('zubairoliyatofficial@gmail.com', 'Zubair Nazer');

     $mail->Subject = 'Verify Your Email';
     $mail->Body    = "http://localhost/user-management/verify.php?key=$verification_key&id=$id";
     $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

     if(!$mail->send()) {
         echo 'Message could not be sent.';
         echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     } else {
         echo 'Message has been sent';
     }

   }else{
    $fmsg .= "Failed to register user";
   }
  }else{
   $fmsg = "Password not matching";
  }
 }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>User Registration Script in PHP & MySQL</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" ></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#usernameLoading').hide();
 $('#username').keyup(function(){
   $('#usernameLoading').show();
      $.post("check.php", {
        username: $('#username').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#usernameResult').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('usernameResult', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
     return false;
 });
});

function finishAjax(id, response) {
  $('#usernameLoading').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
} //finishAjax
</script>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
      <?php if(isset($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <?php echo $smsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
      <?php if(isset($fmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fmsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
      <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Register</h2>
        <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="<?php if(isset($username) & !empty($username)){ echo $username; } ?>" required>
   <span id="usernameLoading" class="input-group-addon"><img src="loading.gif" height="30px" alt="Ajax Indicator" /></span>
  </div>
  <span id="usernameResult"></span>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" value="<?php if(isset($email) & !empty($username)){ echo $email; } ?>" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password Again</label>
        <input type="password" name="passwordagain" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password Again" required>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeQ3K0UAAAAAM4QHKFXmNL_6xrCqa6qlSS1NdXi"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" href="login.php">Login</a>
      </form>
</div>
<?php require_once('credits.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when the user tries to register, no error is showing and the values are not added to the database. Also, it's simply reloading the page. Can anyone please tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: '*no error is showing*' - Is error reporting enabled? Have you checked your logs?

Comment: @Script47 yes, nothing is showing, the page is reloaded simply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I've managed to spot is that you're trying to define a variable within an echo, when you do the insert. Try having '$sql' just by itself like below... hope this helps :)

```html
<?php 
$sql = "INSERT INTO `usermanagement` (username, email, password, verification_key) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', '$verification_key')";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
 ?>
```